# zsh: command not found: on every package I install via npm | MAC OSX CATALINA

Tags: macos, zsh, macos-catalina

When I check versions on node and npm they both return fine and up to date. However, whenever I try to do anything with npm - compile sass, run tsc commands for typescript or work with React, I get this error: zsh: command not found: serve for example.

I believe it is an issue with my pathing, that I simply cannot sort out how to rectify, but I'm tired of getting these errors so I'm hoping I can find help here.

Here is my path when I run echo $PATH:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Here is my .zprofile:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.9
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin
alias python="python3"

git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}

export PS1="[\u@\h \W]\$(git_branch)\$ "
```

**Here is my .zshrc file:**

```
    # If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/JMitchelReed/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable bi-weekly auto-update checks.
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to automatically update without prompting.
# DISABLE_UPDATE_PROMPT="true"

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# export UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS=13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# Caution: this setting can cause issues with multiline prompts (zsh 5.7.1 and newer seem to work)
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/5765
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git zsh-z)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.

#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

alias bc='cd /Users/JMitchelReed/Documents/*JUNO-CLASSES/JunoBootCamp'
alias plant='cd /Users/JMitchelReed/Documents/*JUNO-CLASSES/JunoBootCamp/ProjectTwo/plantAPI'

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

**and if need be here is my .bash_profile**

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.9
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin/:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/X11/bin
alias python="python3"


git_branch() {
  git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}

export PS1="[\u@\h \W]\$(git_branch)\$ "
```

I know these things are a mess, I was just learning a lot of this stuff when I was messing around a while ago, but now I need it for work. I'm grateful for any help in sorting out this mess!